# Duplicate interface definition for class "ViewController"

Tags: ios, objective-c

At the last line, I got the error: `Duplicate interface definition for class "ViewController".` I want to do an IBAction. What is the fault? What can I do? Please help me.

```
//
//  ViewController.h


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
@interface SimpleEmailViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
- (IBAction)showEmail:(id)sender;
@end
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate> {

}
-(IBAction)sendMessage:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)showEmail:(id)sender;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIWebView *site   ;
- (IBAction)call:(id)sender;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *myBotton;
@end
@interface ViewController : UIViewController**i**
```

Comment: what is the last line: `@interface ViewController : UIViewController**i**`? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Why does your `ViewController.h` have three `@interface` lines? That's really strange. It typically has one.

Comment: You have two classes that indicate they're conforming to MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate, which only contains one method 
mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:error:  That I don't see defined in either.  I'm not sure what the last line is trying to do - what's an **i**?  You're also combining old style property lifecycle directives (retain) with ARC ones (strong).  I think you need to take a few steps back and learn the basics - then try this again. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC.pdf

Comment: I added the third @interface because I want to make an IBAction. I want to to this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBmCTjriibQ But it does‘t want to connect with interface ViewController : UIViewController

Comment: *@interface ViewController : UIViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just make it simple like this?

```
//  ViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate>
   // Actions
   - (IBAction)showEmail:(id)sender;
   - (IBAction)sendMessage:(id)sender;
   - (IBAction)call:(id)sender;

   // Properties
   @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIWebView *site;
   @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *myBotton;
@end
```

Comment: And what's about @interface ViewController : UIViewController <MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate> {

Comment: Why did you delete it?

Comment: @David just added the other Protocol to the UIViewController, my bad.

Comment: Thank you. Now, I have: //

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>

(a)interface ViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
(a)property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
(a)property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
// Actions
- (IBAction)showEmail:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)sendMessage:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)call:(id)sender;

// Properties
(a)property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIWebView *site;
(a)property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *myBotton;
(a)end

Comment: How can I set (a)interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate> here now?

Comment: @David No need to beg man, just add the UIScrollViewDelegate Protocol in the same way we did with the other two: `@interface ViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate >`. Then I guess you would want to add too another property which is gonna be the UIScrollView: `@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is exactly what the error states. You defined `@interface viewController` twice. Change the name of one to something else. As a side note, it is a terrible idea to name something with a name apple has already used. You should change both `viewController`s to something else, more descriptive of what it does, like mailViewController or setupViewController. Weird stuff can happen when you use apple defined names.

```
@interface FSMainiPadViewController : UIViewController
```

Comment: Can I really change "ViewController" in Custom Class>Class to an other name?

Comment: I just added a line of code to my answer showing the name of one of my classes. Also, as @rmaddy said above in a comment on your question, usually there is only one `@interface` in a file. Only in certain circumstances is it normal to have multiple.